# Intuition for Relative Phase of Energy-State Qubits

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, quantum-measurements, intuition

Consider a general qubit $|\Psi \rangle = \alpha |0 \rangle + \beta |1\rangle$.

My understanding is as follows:

If such a qubit is implemented using electron spin, for example, the computational basis can be chosen such that $|0\rangle$ corresponds to spin along the $+z$ axis, while $|1\rangle$ corresponds to spin in the opposite direction, $-z$. Then a superposition corresponds to spin distributed along the $x$ and $y$ axes. For example, a state $|0\rangle + |1\rangle$ corresponds to a spin vector along the $+x$ axis. We can then measure in the 'Hadamard basis' by simply measuring the spin along the $x$ axis, as opposed to the computational basis along $z$.

Now, consider an implementation using energy eigenstates as computational basis vectors. For example, the electronic energy levels of the Hydrogen atom, where $|0\rangle$ is the ground state, and $|1\rangle$ is the first excited state. In this case, what does a state such as $|0\rangle + |1\rangle$ represent intuitively (i.e. other than simply a probability distribution)? Is there a way that we can measure in alternative bases to the computational basis (e.g. the Hadamard basis with eigenvectors $|0\rangle+|1\rangle$ and $|0\rangle - |1\rangle$)?

Note: I am aware that states such as $|0\rangle + |1\rangle$ may in principle be transformed to the computational basis vectors and then measured in that basis, but I am interested in the possibility of directly measuring in another basis.

Comment: This is much more difficult to answer intuitively. You could ask the same question about some even more far-out state, like a superposition of a cat being alive and dead at the same time... But yes all of the bases are possible and one can distinguish between $|0\rangle\pm |1\rangle$ with interference experiments